# My formula only keeps one word and not anything after spaces

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am basically trying to omitted all illegal characters and numbers in a soft drinks column. I currently have something like this:

```
Soft Drinks
Dr Pepper;1234
Pepsi369
Coca Cola
Red Bull
Mountain Dew;11
Gatorade
Fanta
Crush Soda456
```

Essentially I want something like this:

```
Soft Drinks
Dr Pepper
Pepsi
Coca Cola
Red Bull
Mountain Dew
Gatorade
Fanta
Crush Soda
```

I tried using this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A9&"", "[a-zA-Z]+"))` but instead I am only getting the first word in the list please see below:

```
Soft
Dr
Pepsi
Coca
Red
Mountain
Gatorade
Fanta
Crush
```

Not sure where I gone wrong. I even tried fixing the regex like this and it still dont work: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A9&"", "[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work: `[a-zA-Z\s]+`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A9&"", "[a-zA-Z\s]+"))
```

[image]

I only added `\s` so that space between words would also be included in your pattern. You can also use `[a-zA-Z ]+`, as using `\s` would match any whitespace character.

Comment: Perfect, works now. Thank you so much!! I accepted your answer now. On an unrelated note, when I download my google sheet and open in Excel I can't replicate the same formula. Do you know if I have to modify anything in Excel?

Comment: Sorry to say, but Excel doesn't have `REGEXEXTRACT` formula, which is crucial here. The logic will be completely different in Excel. You should ask a separate question on how to translate this formula to Excel, because there could be many options, which are not trivial.

Comment: I tried using your formula for words with a number inbetween like `Red Bull R3 Drink ` but was  instead getting `Red Bull R`. I used this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A&"","[a-z0-9A-Z\s]+"))`

Comment: But now Crush Soda456 should fail. Hopefully, this value was just for test and you don't have it in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Use this working, better for you formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"[\d]+$|;","")))
```

[image]

See problem with other formula [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jHVW.png).

Comment: Thanks SIr! If you could be kind and explain the formula you used that would be greatly appreciated!!